# Export all react components in Webpack bundle file and use in html file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have some React components and I want to create a bundle file including them and use it in another HTML file.

What I did:
I created a Webpack config file that gets index.js in `/src` folder as an entry file and generates a bundle file like `components.js`

I ***exported*** all components in the `/src/index.js` file and I suppose that all of them are accessible after bundling with Webpack

I used External key in Webpack to only generate bundle file from my source, not external libs

At the end I put react and bundle file scripts in the HTML file and I want to use them as pure javascript function.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="headerContent"></header>
    <section id="newsContent"></section>
    <section id="categoryContent"></section>
    <footer id="footerContent" ></footer>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="components.js"></script></body>

    <script>
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HeaderComponent), document.getElementById("headerContent"))
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(NewsComponent), document.getElementById("newsContent"))
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(NewsComponent), document.getElementById("categoryContent"))
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(FooterComponent), document.getElementById("footerContent"))
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it does not work. Did I something wrong and what is the best solution?
Webpack Config:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    // Don't bundle the 'react' npm package with the component.
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom' : 'ReactDOM'
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your webpack config ?

Comment: @Sylvain I provided it. Please take a look.

Comment: Is there anymore configuration (dynamically generated or else) ? You don't seems to have an entry and an output.
Is your "components.js" file generated ?

Comment: I think the default entry for the Webapck is src. Plus, it is not completed and just let it be. I think that I should use another Webpack loader to expose all components which be usable in HTML raw file.

Comment: It's true, the default entry is ./src/index.js . However, it seems the default output is ./dist/main.js (and not components.js)
Could you provide the (relevant if too long) content of index.js ?

Comment: Yes. actually, the name is not the problem. My question is related to exposing components in a way that I can use in HTML file like the sample that I provided. Which webpack loaders should I use an how the config file should be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189821/discussion-between-sylvain-and-peekbyte).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is assigning the component to a variable in the window object. In this way, there is no need to change the Webpack config.

```
window.HeaderComponent = HeaderComponent
```

And we can use components in other HTML files.

```
   <script>
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(window.HeaderComponent), document.getElementById("headerContent"))
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(window.NewsComponent), document.getElementById("newsContent"))
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(window.NewsComponent), document.getElementById("categoryContent"))
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(window.FooterComponent), document.getElementById("footerContent"))
    </script>
```